# MySQL foreign key and xref table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to understand MySQL xref table and foreign key structures.

I have three tables with the following structures;

table_food

```
| id | name        |
|  1 | apple_pie   |
|  2 | pumpkin_pie |
```

table_ingredient

```
| id | name       |
|  1 | apple      |
|  2 | pumpkin    |
|  3 | milk       |
|  4 | flour      | 
|  5 | soy_milk   |
```

table_food_ingredient

```
| food_id | ingredient_id |
| 1       | 1             |
| 1       | 3             |
| 1       | 4             |
| 2       | 2             |
| 2       | 3             |
```

I know how to get the ingredients from the table_food_ingredient to get all ingredient to apple_pie, should be the code below

```
SELECT ingredient_id FROM table_food_ingredient WHERE food_id = 1;
```

But I can't figure out how I get food_id from all the matching ingredient_id.

for example i want to get food_id if i select ingredient_id of 1, 3, 4 which should only give me food_id of 1(apple_pie)

Comment: A discussion of associative entities (cross reference tables) can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity. and foreign keys here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html. You do not need foreign keys for what you wish to achieve but you should research indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, if I understood correctly we must recover the number of the food according to the ingredients.

### What is the problem ?

We want to retrieve a **single result** but the table contains **multiple lines for a single id.**
So we can't doing this with simple `SELECT .. WHERE`.

### The solution

A beginning of solution is in this link [Select all rows with multiple conditions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75607/select-all-rows-with-multiple-conditions-in-another-table).

> You can get the result by using a combination of a `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT f.id, f.name
FROM table_food f
INNER JOIN table_food_ingredient fi
    ON f.id = fi.food_id
WHERE fi.ingredient_id in(1, 3, 4)
GROUP BY f.id, f.name
HAVING count(distinct fi.ingredient_id) = 3;
```

Comment: `WHERE fi.ingredient_id = 1 AND fi.ingredient_id = 3 AND fi.ingredient_id = 4` - This can not match any row. One value cannot be equal to three different values.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Should use OR operator ?

Comment: Better use `IN(1,3,4)` like in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT food_id FROM Table1 WHERE ingredient_id in(1,3,4)
GROUP BY food_id
HAVING count(distinct ingredient_id)=3;
```

> `ingredient_id in(1,3,4)` - contains all the ingredients. 
>   `count(distinct ingredient_id)=3;` - The number should be count of ingredients in
>   `IN`